# Different homepage for logged in users

Tags: login

Hi I would love to show different content for logged in users and I don't want to use a redirect, I came up with this idea and it worked well but I am not sure if it is the right way

```
//Home.php file
If is_loggedin(){
get_header('login');
//My content
get_sidebar('login');
get_footer('login');
}
elseif (! is_loggedin()){
get_header();
//My content
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
}
```

I am using my own custom made theme, it worked fine but I want to know if it is advisable

Comment: That is not related to your question, by why using `elseif (! is_loggedin()){` instead of `else {`? User can be logged in or not logged in, there are no third variant.

Answer (score 1):

What is the is_loggedin() function ? Is that something you have create by yourself ?

Wordpress already got what you need, : **[is_user_logged_in()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/)**

You can use **[is_home()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home/)** & is_user_logged_in() to be sure that the content will not display on other page.

As @Ivan Shatsky say's, don't use "else condition" like that.

```
    //Home.php file
    if (is_home() && is_user_logged_in()) {
        get_header('login');
        //My content
        get_sidebar('login');
        get_footer('login');
    } else {
        get_header();
       //My content
       get_sidebar();
       get_footer();
    }
```

Not tested !